# how secure is passing query in url

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, url, google-cloud-firestore

i'm selling a few courses online, so for the payment cart i implemented a method that gets the course data from firestore through the query in the url e.g: `localhost:5000/?product=course1`.

so, i want to know how secure is it, in terms of injection or other vulnerabilities

i implemented simple validation. but nothing major.

this is the products post request:

```
router.post("/courses", (req, res) => {
  const product = req.body.product;

  res.redirect("/payment?product=" + product);
});
```

this is the payment page:

```
router.get("/payment", async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.query.product);

  const snapshot = await db.collection("products").get();
  const products = await snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
    return {
      name: doc.id,
      price: doc.data().price
    };
  });
  thisProduct = products.find(product => {
    return req.query.product === product.name;
  });
  console.log(thisProduct);
  if (typeof thisProduct == "undefined") {
    return res.send("product not found");
  }

  res.render("payment", {
    key: "pk_test_fVJwSNZpMoCwrF7Zs48PsLR100zpmBhXrc",
    user: true,
    title: "Pay for a course",
    product: {
      name: thisProduct.name,
      price: thisProduct.price
    }
  });
});
```

please let me know if there is any vulnerabilty and how to fix them. 
comment if you don't find any vulnerabilty.
thank you!

Comment: As long as the data passed in the URL isn't executable - it looks like a simple choice here - then it should be fine. POST requests or cookies are always better because you can't find the data by accident, but this should be okay for what you're doing.

Comment: Since `req.query.product === product.name` is the only place you’re using it, it should be quite safe. It does look inefficient, though, unless Firestore does some kind of magic. (I doubt it.) As for the other route: I wouldn’t redirect without validating the product name.

Comment: @Ry- what do you mean with validating the product name?

Comment: @MendiSterenfeld what he means is how do you know `req.query.product` is a valid product? You are currently trusting the client to be correct with that particular API.

Comment: @James if the product doesn't exist I just send ’res.send("product not found");’ isn't that enough?

Comment: @MendiSterenfeld you do that on the payment page, not the courses API, some basic validation in there wouldn't go a miss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any vulnerabilities in the code you showed. Generally, to avoid any kind of injection you should validate all your inputs properly. I.e. if you expect a `product` to be a number you should check that it is a number. Also, a general practice to avoid SQL injections is to not use string interpolation (and you don't ) for SQL queries but instead use prepared statements or/and ORM.

So, sending params in URL query is as safe as sending any other kind of params while you're taking all precautions.